# Download JavaScript Generated Binary from Tornado

Tags: pdf, tornado, pdfkit

I'm using [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org) to generate a PDF in the browser.  I'm then posting the PDF to a tornado webserver, which I want to return to the browser as a download.  Here is the request handler:

```
class PDF(RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        logger.info("Received PDF.")
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
        self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.pdf"')
        self.write(self.request.body)
        logger.info("Returning PDF.")
```

However, the downloaded PDF appears to be URL-encoded (slashes appear as %2F, etc.).  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you sure it's not the uploaded PDF that has these issues? perhaps it's an issue with the way you encode your upload form?

Comment: You're right.  So I'm actually base64-encoding the uploaded PDF first.  I'm now decoding on the server side, so the file looks better, but it's still not being recognized as a valid PDF.

Comment: did you try to save it to a local file on the server and not return it from tornado, just to rule out tornado as having something to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually a combination of base64 decoding and URL unescaping.  The following works now:

```py
class PDF(RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
        self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.pdf"')
        self.write(b64decode(escape.url_unescape(self.request.body.split("=")[1])))
```